# binding <select> change event using jQueryMobile/PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to run following html/JS code in PhoneGap,
but the alert dialog is not shown up and the following line is in the LogCat window;
the following warning appeared and alert did not showed.

[ERROR]

> W/InputManagerService(266): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient

I jus want to fetch selected value on the change of the value, what's the problem? please help

[CODE]

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $("#selectcount").change(function() {
            alert('hello');
        }).change();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" data-role="page">  
    <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Number:</label>
    <select id="selectcount" name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0">
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100" selected="selected">100</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you loading jquery mobile?

Also, your code needs to be wrapped in the [document ready function](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectcount").change(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry, jQM is loaded right after the <head> open tag. i snipped for the post. for wrapping document.ready function I made a easy mistake! thank you

Comment: An easy mistake indeed. Happens to the best of us. Could you please check as answered? Thanks!